# Mysql left join and null

Tags: mysql, null, left-join

I have a base table and many query results

first is the base list:

```
a, b
name1, type1
name2, type2
name3, type3
name4, type4
```

b is an ID

others are SELECT result like this (count the types in the other table)

```
null, 5
type1, 3
type4, 3
```

null is 5 because in the other table many rows haven't any type

if I use LEFT JOIN

```
type1, 3
type4, 3
```

and not null row, because null not included in a base list

I did a trick:

```
SELECT a, b 
FROM table1 
UNION
SELECT "none", null 
FROM table1
```

result:

```
name1, type1 
name2, type2
...
name4, type4
none, null
```

BUT if I tried the LEFT JOIN, no change

```
name1, type1, 3
name2, type2, null
...
name4, type4, 3
none, null, null
```

how can I put the null, 5 value in the joined result?
(ok I can use the RIGHT and LEFT OUTER JOIN, but I have many result tables, which I want to join the base list)

Thank you so much, and sorry for my poor english :)

Comment: I think you're trying to achieve a `full outer join`, which unfortunately isn't supported in in mySQL.  The behavior can be mimic'd by using LEFT/RIGHT and union as you suggested.   [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796872/full-outer-join-in-mysql)

Comment: show us real data sample of both tables and post expected result set. and post full query string not just  *others are SELECT* or *BUT if I tried the LEFT JOIN,*

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem. 
I read in mysql docs, working with nulls
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/working-with-null.html
"You cannot use arithmetic comparison operators such as =, <, or <> to test for NULL."
So I changed the ON clause:

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT... ) a
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT... ) b
ON a.id = b.id OR (a.id IS NULL AND b.id IS NULL)
```

and `b select` joined to `a select` with null value